# Function out of scope

Tags: haskell, web, message, yesod

I have a doubt of why is this happening. I have been following the "Yesod Web" ebook but with a scaffolded site. When I arrived to a position that I wanted to apply the function of "plural" inside a "messages" file, the compiler returns this error:

Foundation.hs:52:1: Not in scope: `plural'

Where plural is declared in the same hs file as the one that I am calling the "hamlet" one. However, if I move the function declaration before the line #52 in the "Foundation.hs" file, then the error vanishes and it let me compile it effectively. Why does this happen??

```
module Handler.UserProfile where

import Import
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Data.Text (pack, unpack)

viewCountName :: Text
viewCountName = "UserProfileViews"

readInt :: String -> Int
readInt = read

plural :: Int -> String -> String -> String
plural 1 x _ = x
plural _ _ y = y

getUserProfileR :: Handler RepHtml
getUserProfileR = do

    viewCount <- lookupSession viewCountName
                >>= return . (1 +) . readInt . unpack . fromMaybe "0"
    setSession viewCountName (pack $ show viewCount)

    maid <- maybeAuth
    --msg <- getMessageRender
    let user = case maid of
                    Nothing -> "(Unknown User ID)" --show MsgHello --
                    Just (Entity _ u) -> userEmail u
    defaultLayout $ do
        setTitleI MsgUserProfile
        $(widgetFile "nhUserProfile")
```

Comment: I don't really know Yesod, but see the `$(...)`?  That is template haskell -- code that is executed at compile time, and I believe it can only see definitions that are before it is used.

Comment: Note that when luqui says "before it is used" he really does mean this is an issue of location. Contrary to the rest of Haskell-land, the code from the start of the source file down to any given template Haskell splice (`$(...)`) must be self-contained.

Comment: @luqui Mind making that into an answer so that this question does not get counted as unanswered by SO stats.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the GHC users manual: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html#id684916

The staging restriction in play is described in the second bullet point:

> You can only run a function at compile time if it is imported from
>   another module. That is, you can't define a function in a module, and
>   call it from within a splice in the same module. (It would make sense
>   to do so, but it's hard to implement.)